# Find value in 2 different sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

So, as you can see from the example google sheet below, is there any way to have a formula in which when you try to find the value from both sheets (Example 1, Example 2; if lets say in Example 3, when you try to find the value in Example 1 sheet, it finds nothing and it proceeds to Example 2 sheet to look for the value and if there's any value found, it will return the value to the respective cell)

If =iferror(vlookup(C2,Example1!B:C,2,false)) is empty, try =iferror(vlookup(C3,Example2!B:C,2,false)) to find value in 2 different sheets

Thank you.

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OvyDTfUcrvVUFUptYbmUZ2aYvkq-ON1wfrFyQTM0OCw/edit#gid=1588781085

Comment: Welcome. Please correct me if I am wrong. From your sheet I understand -rephrasing your question - that you could want to have the two values returned in one formula. Would that be sufficient?

Comment: Hi, i managed to solve it and found the formula:
=if(iferror(vlookup(C2,Example1!B:C,2,false))="",vlookup(C3,Example2!B:C,2,false))

To return the value if it is found in either one of the 2 sheets. That was what i was asking.

But somehow that code works but, for some values in my other sheet it's returning 'FALSE' but not for some others, why?

Comment: This returns `FALSE` in your example sheet as well. Sorry to repeat myself: _could you probably **just** want to have the two values returned in one formula. Would that be sufficient?_

Comment: Just 1 value, the formula to find in the first sheet and if it doesn't find anything there, proceed to the second sheet, so in the end we will only have 1 value returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround would be to use curly brackets `{}`

For "Bananas" use the following formula 


```
=QUERY({iferror(vlookup(C2,Example1!B:C,2,false));iferror(vlookup(C2,Example2!B:C,2,false))},"select * where Col1 is not null")
```

You could also use a "corrected" form of your mentioned formula

```
=IFS(iferror(vlookup(C2,Example2!B:C,2,false))="",vlookup(C2,Example1!B:C,2,false),iferror(vlookup(C2,Example1!B:C,2,false))="",vlookup(C2,Example2!B:C,2,false))
```

Please read more about [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)

Have a look at the [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10LHP-ipo-xT2HtgwxB1BZ8mS5KOhcWz3RpymuEyoHmU/edit#gid=1925180077&range=E2)

Comment: Nono, not using arrays, it returns #REF! anyways. Is there a workaround with my code?

=if(iferror(vlookup(C2,Example1!B:C,2,false))="",vlookup(C3,Example2!B:C,2,false))

Comment: Please have a look at the updated formula

Comment: _"Nono, not using arrays"_. Why not if it solves your issue? In any case the updated formula does not return any `#REF!`

Comment: Added the _"corrected"_ form of your mentioned formula.

Comment: I know it is an old question. Still. Have you tried the given solution? Did it work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well. Consider it your contribution to those who help **you** solve your issues with Google sheets.

Comment: yes i just marked it as solved, im sorry for the delay. This works, so thank you for the solution.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept.